# Android there is no ListView adapter resourceId

Tags: android, xml, android-arrayadapter, listadapter

based on Hello-ListView turorial in Android, http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html

on the

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, COUNTRIES));
```

had an error because there is no R.layout.list_item

previously i had followed the tutorial, created the file list_item.xml on the res/layout folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="10dp"
android:textSize="16sp">
</TextView>
```

it doesnt work with different name neither (main_list_view.xml)

this is the complete source

```
String[] appList;

ListView mainLv;    

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main); 
    appList = this.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.for_main_layout);
    mainLv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListView01); 
    mainLv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, appList)); //<<
}
```

Updated!
Ah its works now when creating new project! When i use File>new>Android XML File in the first project, it doesnt work, but now in different project, i use file>new>File, maybe is this a possible bug?

Comment: So do you have a file in your res/layout directory named list_item.xml?

Comment: yes of course, inside the res/layout directory res/layout/list_item.xml, the bulp says "list_item cannot be resolved or is not a field"

Comment: Ah its works now when creating new project! When i use File>new>Android XML File in the first project, it doesnt work, but now in different project, i use file>new>File, maybe is this a possible bug? Oh it doesnt seem to be a bug, in new scenario i tried with the xml and it works normaly!

Answer (score 0):

it doesnt seem to be a bug, in new scenario I tried with the xml and it works normaly

So I just create a new project.

But I dont know the first.

Answer (score 0):

You could have used the android supplied layout:

```
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1
```

Try that one.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Project -> Clean? the way it looks you're R.java isn't beeing updated, either project->clean or there is some error in xml most of times.